# how to specialize std::hash call operator for return types other than size_t?

Tags: c++, hashtable, c++17

This is the first time I've tried using `std::unordered_map`, c++17. I'm trying to build a quick `LRU` where I'm mapping `sha1` digests to blocks of data. My `sha1` object is fully comparable etc, but when I try to instantiate the map, I get this error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/hashtable_policy.h:87:34: error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<
kbs::crypto::basic_digest<20,kbs::crypto::openssl_sha1_digest_engine_policy> >) (const kbs::crypto::basic_digest<20, kbs::crypto::openssl_sha1_digest_engine_policy>&)’
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
```

So it looks like I can specialize `std::hash` for my user defined type. But, it always returns `size_t`, which is bad, going from 20 bytes to 8 bytes kinda defeats the purpose of using sha1 for a hash_key.

Is there a way to work around this? Alternative containers? It's a waste to have to write my own hashmap. I guess I could use std:set...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to *do* with this hash table that you *need* a 20-byte hash code?

Comment: Please provide code, not just an error message. [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are usually most helpful.

Comment: @Xirema It's a data storage array, the LRU would manage the read cache.

Comment: I see some openSSL features, which are C level and this is probably source of your problems. Also hash in a map is completely different thing then hash used in security!

Comment: I think you misunderstand the purpose of the hash for `std::unordered_map`. It's only used to assign a bucket, the algorithm is designed to handle multiple keys mapping to the same bucket.

Comment: *"it always returns size_t"* - by-design. 20.9.3 [unord.hash] defines the behavior of `std::hash`, requiring 17.6.3.4 [hash.requirements], and how the unordered containers utilize it. If you want a different behavior; you need a different container and a different hashing ideology. It almost sounds like you want the behavior of a radix tree (which could work, but not something the std lib is going ot give you for free). Personally I'd let `unordered_map` deal with the collisions for you and just write a `std::hash` specialization for your key type, following the rules of `std::hash`.

Comment: @MarekR It's just a veneer over openssl, or any hash engine. The class just takes data and calls static "engine" methods to obtain the digest. So with with one base class and a static class I can declare a digest like so, using sha1 = basic_digest<20, openssl_sha1_digest_engine_policy>; specialize less_than and move on. Makes it really easy to try out different crypto engines system wide.

Comment: @ppetraki just edit question to provide code you have problem with. After that guessing what you need and what is your problem will end.

Comment: Why not use `std::map<sha1, data>` instead of `unordered_map`? You don't need a hash then (but you will need a "less than" operator on the sha1)

Comment: @MarshallClow I think you're right. I reached for the shiny new thing first :). I just want fast look ups. If it turns out that it's not fast enough I can try the solution yakk-adam-nevraumont proposed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unordered map does not assume the hashes (the `size_t`s) are unique.  It assumes keys are.  And it performs well if the hashes are *good*.

Unordered map uses the `size_t` to determine which bucket to put the data into.  It handles collisions in the `size_t` space fine.

Map your sha hash to a `size_t` however you want, and use the sha hash as your key.  In the unlikely event you get a `size_t` hashing collision (50/50 when you have roughly 4 billion elements in the unordered map, assuming good hashing - see "birthday paradox " for the math, or more often with smaller hash tables; it dynamically grows the table) it will fall back on equality of your sha hash keys to avoid "real" collisions.

There are multiple kinds of collisions.

- Sha-hash collisions: bad, means same key different data.
- size_t hash collisions: meh, means the two elements will always be in same bucket.
- internal hash table collisions: common, means that at this specific size, the two elements are in the same bucket.

Unless most of your data maos to the same size_t, that map being lossy is perfectly fine.  You just worry about the first kind of collision, and provide `==` on your sha-hashes.